# Interaction of directive and controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a component that displays itself as a collapsible box.
When it is expanded, it should show the transcluded content; when it is collapsed it should only show its label.

```
myApp.directive('collapsingBox', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    require: '^ngModel',
    scope: {
      ngModel: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-controller="CollapseController" class="collapsingBox"><div class="label">Title: {{ ngModel.title }}</div><br/><div ng-transclude ng-show="expanded">Test</div></div>',
    link: function($scope, element, attr) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        alert('Clicked!');
        $scope.toggle();
      });
    }
  };

});
```

This component should be reusable and nestable, so I wanted to manage the values (like "title" and "expanded") in a controller that gets instantiated for every use of the directive:

```
myApp.controller('CollapseController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.expanded = true;

  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.expanded = !$scope.expanded;
  };
}]);
```

This "almost" seems to work:
http://plnkr.co/edit/pyYV0MAikXThvMO8BF69

The only thing that does not work seems to be accessing the controller's scope from the event handler bound during linking.

```
link: function($scope, element, attr) {
  element.bind('click', function() {
    alert('Clicked!');
    $scope.toggle(); // this is an error -- toggle is not found in scope
  });
}
```

1. Is this the correct (usual?) way to create one instance of the controller per use of the directive?
2. How can I access the toggle-Function from the handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using `ng-controller` on your directive's template, you need to put the controller in your directive's `controller` property:

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  require: '^ngModel',
  scope: {
    ngModel: '='
  },
  template: '<div class="collapsingBox"><div class="label">Title: {{ ngModel.title }}</div><br/><div ng-transclude ng-show="expanded">Test</div></div>',
  controller: 'CollapseController',
  link: function($scope, element, attr) {
    element.bind('click', function() {
      alert('Clicked!');
      $scope.toggle();
    });
  }
};
```

As it is `CollapseController`'s scope will be a child scope of your directive's scope, which is why `toggle()` isn't showing up there.

Comment: This does what I want, mostly - although the visibility does not update, so I probably am missing some watch/binding. After reading the documentation and some tutorials I had been under the impression that the controller property is intended for sharing one controller for all instances (for communication between instances).

Comment: I had to use $scope.$apply() to update the values in .toggle().